# How ISo day works in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, date, mongoose

I am trying to find the exact date of a product creation date.
I am using default Iso date.

Here I am console logging the date of the product

```
.get((req, res) => {
    const match = {
      shop_id: req.params.shop_id,
      createdAt: { $gte: new Date(2021, 0, 1) },
    };
    console.log(match)
```

As you can see here I am trying to find the day greater than `2021,Jan,1st` which is the result i wanted.

But program is actually searching for is  createdAt: `{ '$gte': 2020-12-31T17:00:00.000Z }`

```
2020,dec,31
```

Which is not i wanted?
Can someone explain how this works and how to filter the exact date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to time zones. According to your profile, you are located in Myanmar.

Notice how there's a 7 hour difference between the two timestamps? The ISO date includes a "Z" at the end. It signifies that this timestamp is in UTC time (+0) while you're at +7. [The "Z" stands for "Zulu time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)); 0.

You can create a new `Date` object that is not in your current timezone with [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

```
createdAt: { $gte: new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 0, 1)) },
// Searches for 2021-01-01 00:00:00 +0 (or "Z")
```

---

Edit:

> Which is not i wanted?

The behavior *might actually be* what you wanted; if you insert a record into MongoDB with a date at `00:00:00 Myanmar time`, it will be stored in the database as `the previous day at 17:00:00 UTC time`, because MongoDB stores dates at UTC (by default).

When you query, you'd actually *want* the query to be `$gte 17:00:00Z`,  in this case. After all: that is midnight in Myanmar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I also want to search for `2021, 0, 1` + 1 date
with `$lt`  How to add 1 date

Comment: You can put them right next to each other: `createdAt: { $gte new Date(Date.UTC(2021,0,1)), $lt: new Date(Date.UTC(2021,0,2)) }`. If you need to calculate dates (like say, "if its 2021-02-28 12:00:00, what day is it tomorrow?"), you can use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).